# Is there a query to retrieve data from Sybase table on record count condition

Tags: python, sap-ase

I have a situation where I need to select records from a Sybase table based on a certain condition

1. Record needs to extract on batches. If the total count is 2000 then I need to extract 500 in first batch and 500 in next batch till 2000 record count is reached.
2. I used the limit condition but it's giving a incorrect syntax

```
select top 2 * 
from CERD_CORPORATE..BOOK 
where id_bo_book in('5330') 
limit(2,3)
```

Comment: You have a typo in CERD_CORPORATE..BOOK, aren't you?

Comment: which version of ASE?  support for `limit/offset` doesn't show up until ASE 16.x

Comment: If its not 16.x then is there any other way I can do the task. The table might have 20k records and it may required to extract 1500 records in each select statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the range for `LIMIT` condition, but you can use [OFFSET](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/select_limit.php) keyword for this:

```
SELECT top 2 * FROM CERD_CORPORATE.BOOK 
WHERE id_bo_book in('5330') 
LIMIT 2 OFFSET 1;
```

Comment: Thanks but no luck. Still its saying incorrect syntax near limit

Answer (score 0):

On ASE 12.5.1 and onwards this can be done with a "SQL Derived Table" or "Inline View". The query requires that each row has a unique key so the table can be joined with itself and a count of the rows where the key value is less than the row being joined can be returned. This gives a monotonically increasing number with which to specify the limit and offset.

The equivalents of limit and offset are the values compared against x.rowcounter.

```
select
        x.rowcounter,
        x.error,
        x.severity
    from
        (
            select
                    t1.error,
                    t1.severity,
                    t1.description,
                    count(t2.error) as rowcounter
                from
                    master..sysmessages t1,
                    master..sysmessages t2
                where
                    t1.error >= t2.error
                group by
                    t1.error,
                    t1.severity,
                    t1.description
        ) x
    where
        x.rowcounter >= 50
    and x.rowcounter < 100
```

SQL Derived Tables are available as far back as Sybase ASE 12.5.1, [SQL Derived Tables](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.dc32300_1251/html/sqlug/CHDGJGFB.htm)

The use of master..sysmessages in the example provides a reasonable (10,000 rows) data set with which to experiment.